# Reproducing kernel Hilbert space of Matérn kernels

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sobolev-spaces, kernels

I am trying to read a recent paper titled *"Interpolation and learning with scale dependent kernels"* by Pagliana, Ruidi, De Vito, and Rosasco. (The paper can be found [on ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09984))

On the top of page 5, they discussing the reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) related to the Matérn kernels, which are defined to be functions of the form
$$
k_\gamma(x, x') = \Big( \frac{\| x - x' \|}{\gamma} \Big)^{s - d/2} K_{s - d/2}\Big( \frac{\| x - x' \|}{\gamma} \Big),
$$
where $K_\alpha$ denotes a modified Bessel function of the second kind with parameter $\alpha$.

The main example of such kernels is the Laplace kernel, which corresponds to $s = (d + 1)/2$ and $k_\gamma(x, x') = \exp{-\| x - x'\| / \gamma}$.

The authors make the following assertions:

> *A peculiar and important property of these kernels is that for $s > d/2$, the RKHS corresponding to different scales are all equivalent to the Sobolev space $W_2^s(\mathcal{X})$ for every $\gamma$. This means that, if a function belongs to $H_\gamma$ for some $\gamma$, then it also belongs to $H_{\gamma'}$ for any other $\gamma'$. However, the same function will have different norms in spaces corresponding to different scale parameters.*

I am trying to reason about these assertions but do not really have the necessary background to do so. I have looked online but so far have not found any resources that I find particularly helpful. Therefore, I wanted to ask if anybody might be able to suggest a reference or provide a sketch of a proof that could help shed any insight on justification for any of the sentences in bold?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/schaback/teaching/AV_2.pdf) script by Robert Schaback Chapter 9.4 contains proofs. The statement above appears there as Theorem 9.9